# csv.writer in Autodesk CSV

Tags: python, csv, writer, autodesk

```
29 csvfile=desfile+"\spv1.csv" 
30 csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
```

I am using AutodDesk CFD with Python, this is the section where I am trying to write the results to a csv file. The variable desfile is the path, I keep getting the error

File "C:/Users/Carlos/Documents/Inventor/Prototype Velocity Profile/Extracting Summary Stats for Expanding Models.py", line 30, in

```
csv_writer = csv.writer('csvfile')
```

TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

I have tried inserting the delimiter options with the writer but still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

`csv.writer` requires a file-like object, not a string...

Try:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(csvfile, 'wb'))
```